# NextJS groupe routing compiling error "neither a posix nor a windows path"

Tags: webpack, next.js

learning nextJS by doing their course (https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/streaming).
When creating a parenthesis folder  (overview) i get this error when compiling :

"uncaughtException: Error: . is neither a posix nor a windows path, and there is no 'join' method defined in the file system at join"

**Package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "seed": "node -r dotenv/config ./scripts/seed.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.6",
    "@types/node": "20.5.7",
    "@vercel/postgres": "^0.5.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "next": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss": "8.4.31",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.14",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.17.0"
  }
}
```

**Folder tree**

- app

  - (overview)

    - page.tsx
    - loading.tsx
  - customers

    - page.tsx
  - invoices

    - page.tsx
  - layout.tsx

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Any idea what might cause this issue ? i'm searching for answers but haven't found yet

Answer (score 0):

I have just hit something similar myself. No amount of restarting the server and deleting the .next folder helped me.

Are you on Windows, by any chance? I noticed that something in node.js doesn't seem to like paths with square brackets on Windows even though the file system supports it. I'm guessing something similar is happening with parenthesis on paths as well, since that tutorial uses them. If you are indeed on Windows, try running node.js under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). I ran Ubuntu 22.04 (`wsl --install Ubuntu-22.04`), deleted the `.next` and `node_modules` folders, reinstalled node modules with `npm install` and restarted the Next.js app. Things worked fine after that.